# PHP and JQuery weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, oracle

I have a 3-tier architecture. The db is oracle, the business/logic layer is php, while the front end is html/JavaScript. My business/logic layer have a bunch of unit tests that only pass if the requirements are met. The problem occurs when I wire the business layer and front end via javascript. After a lot debugging, I found the sources of the problem:

JavaScript code causing error.

```
function getAllUsers() {
        var allUsers = [];
    $.ajax ({
            url: '../php/get-all-users.php',
            success:function(data){
                allUsersJSON = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(allUsersJSON);
                for (var i = 0; i < allUsersJSON.length; i++){
                    allUsers[i] = allUsersJSON[i].USER_NAME;
                }
                console.log(allUsers);
            }
    });

    return allUsers;

}
```

**../php/get-all-users.php**

```
<?php
    include_once 'Database.php'

    $db = Database::instance();  // Singleton to initialize db.
    echo json_encode($db->getAllUsers());
?>
```

**Database.php** fragment.

```
public function createConnection($username, $password, $connectionString){
        $this->_connection = oci_connect($username, $password, $connectionString);
        if (!$this->_connection) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
            throw new Exception("Database connection failed. Please check constructor arguments.");
        }else{
            //print "Database connection established.\n";
        }
    }
```

In one of my tests, I tried **echo json_encode($db->getAllUsers());** and get a result, **"[\"USER_NAME\":\"userName\"]"**. In get-all-users.php, if I comment out everything, and echo the string I get from the tests, the web page now loads fine, but of course this is not what I desired. Furthermore, if I uncomment **include_once 'Database.php'** in get-all-users.php and comment out **oci_connect** in my Database.php, the web page loads fine. This made me conclude that the root of the problem is oci_connect.

Did anyone else have a similar experience? I tried googling but found no result. If you need more information to make light of this problem, I'd gladly spew them out.

Edit:

I'm working in linux. My team mate is working with Windows and he have no problems like this.

Comment: What is your unit test code?

Comment: @lxe My unit test code utilizes PHPUnit. It tests all the modules in my Business layer, one of which is the Database.php. In that test, I establish a connection, do query, and destroy allocated resource, and exit, this is repeated for many different queries..

Comment: "In one of my tests, I tried echo json_encode($db->getAllUsers());" I'm just wondering why you're making a call to the DB there. Why not just query the endpoint?

Comment: @lxe "Why not just query the endpoint?" I don't quite understand that question. What is an endpoint? Anyway, see my new edit, maybe that will help narrow down the possible problems.

Comment: So can you please add a sample of what exactly `$db->getAllUsers()` is returning? also have you tried too add a `console.log(data);` exactly after the `success:function(data){` line?